# MD5 with salt in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, encryption, md5, whmcs

So I'm trying to create a simple application that's connected to WHMCS. The only problem I'm having right now is the password encryption with salt.

The password is stored in the database like password:salt. What I did was fetch it, split the string, then encrypt it.

```
      $hash = md5($salt . $password) . ":" . $salt;
```

That's how WHMCS encrypt the passwords.

http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx
This is the class I'm using to encrypt it.

```
      Dim encoder As New UTF8Encoding()         
      Dim PasswordArray() As String = Split(Password, ":")
      Dim Salt as Byte() = encoder.GetBytes(PasswordArray(1)) 
      Dim HashedPassword As String = SimpleHash.ComputeHash(PasswordTextBox.Text, "MD5", Salt)

      'Check if they are equal
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You appear to be trying to using the salt value `PasswordArray(1)` (the 2nd line of your example) *before* you've actually assigned `PasswordArray` (the third line). Have you tried swapping those two lines?

Comment: Oh, right. It's not actually like that in my script. I forgot the lines on here and added them at the wrong place. I'll edit it right away.